# Creating singe shared object from multiple pyx files in cython

Tags: python, shared-libraries, cython

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

> module
>
> \j.h (header file of constants)
>
> \submodule1
>
> ```
>    f1.pyx (cpdef and cdef functions, extern call from j.h)
>
>    f2.py
> ```
>
> \submodule2
>
> ```
>    g1.pyx (cpdef and cdef functions)
>
>    g2.py
>
>    g1.pxd (header file for cdefs in g1.pyx for cimport in f1.pyx)
> ```

I want to make a single .so file for all the pyx files. I tried creating a 'pyx' file with

```
#include ".\module1\f1.pyx"
#include ".\module2\g1.pyx"
```

to create a single so file. But its not working. Note that I have both cpdefs and cdefs in pyx files.

Errors like this are showing up at compile time:

```
Function signature does not match previous declaration
certain pxd file not found
```

How do I make it to work?